# XML RPC for android - Unable to create the XML parse: org.xml.sax.SaxNotRecognizedException

Tags: java, android, xml-parsing, xml-rpc

My question is exactly [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089432/xml-rpc-problem-in-java-unable-to-create-the-xml-parse-org-xml-sax-saxnotreco) question, only the answer doesn't cut it for me.

The answer simply points to [this](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9493) discussion. The root of the problem there is obviously the same as in the linked SO question, but I don't see how I can apply the workaround mentioned by the end of the thread to my problem.

So the question is: How do I go about to avoid this error in the XML-RPC case - the one described in the linked SO-question

Comment: I can make it work using an apache XML-RPC 2 webserver, but thesame error arrises with redstone xml-rpc. I'll stick to apache xml-rpc 2 for the time being, but I would be very grateful for a solution so I could choose freely!

Comment: I have this problem as well.  It prevents my app from working on lower version of Android.

Answer (score 1):

A possible fix is to prevent apache xml-rpc from setting these features. As these settings are unsupported anyway it shouldn't be a problem (works fine for me).

In version 3.1.3 you need to change org.apache.xmlrpc.util.SAXParsers Lines 37-50:

```
    try {
        spf.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-general-entities", false);
    } catch (javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException e) {
        // Ignore it
    } catch (org.xml.sax.SAXException e) {
        // Ignore it
    }
    try {
        spf.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-parameter-entities", false);
    } catch (javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException e) {
        // Ignore it
    } catch (org.xml.sax.SAXException e) {
        // Ignore it
    }
```

Just comment them out, compile it and replace the original xmlrpc-common jar.

Comment: I'm not in a position to test this now, but I will give an upvote for now. If anyone can confirm this, please make a comment and I will tick this answer as correct!